# How to use DFT to approximate a function?

Tags: java, fft, dft

Im trying to implement something like discribed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), Specifically i want to be able to perform the following operation as in the following image :

[image]

That is, given N discrete points with constant time interval, i want to create a function that converges to those points as in the image...

So far what i did was :

1. imported jtransform
2. used it

   ```
   private double[] doDFT(double[] data, int start, int end) {
       DoubleFFT_1D doubleFFT_1D = new DoubleFFT_1D(end-start);
       double[] array = new double[(end-start)*2];
       for (int i=0;i<end-start;i++) {
           array[i] = data[i+start];
           array[i+1] = data[i+start+1]; 
       }
       doubleFFT_1D.complexForward(array);
       return array;
   }
   ```

and Now im stuck, how do i use the output array to produce the function that converges to the points in the original data array?

Just to clearify what i want : for example in the image the data array that is inputted to doDFT is the blue line plot, and what i want is to produce a function f that its image is the red line plot.

Comment: The red line seems to correspond to the small frequencies of the signal. You may set the high frequency to null `for (int i=14;i<end-start;i++) {array[i] =0}`. Then compute the backward fft `doubleFFT_1D.complexBackward(array);`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to set the imaginary component of your complex input to zero, not to the next point.

The functions you want are sinusoids.  Each sinusoid will have a frequency of an FFT result bin index * Fs/N.  The magnitude and phase of each sinusoid will be given by the complex value corresponding to its FFT result bin.

You can sum an increasing number of these sinusoids, starting with 1, to get your converging waveforms.